# What's going on with xcopy /d

Tags: xcopy

What exactly is under the hood of the /d flag? what is the code doing? Reason I'm asking is that I can't tell definitively if /d is reading the entire file from source or just some header. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

#### What exactly is under the hood of the `/d` flag?

`/d` requires a date argument. It uses the last modifed date of the file.

> Copy files changed on or after the specified date.

Source [Xcopy - Copy files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)

It does not need to read the file itself to get this date as it is retrieved from the file system.